# How to trace the reason/stack trace of query in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, log4net

I have a page where I issue a few queries and all of them are logged using **log4net**:

```
<appender name="NHibernateAppenderSQL" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="c:\dev\log\nhibernate-sql.log" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
  <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
  <levelMax value="FATAL" />
</filter>

<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

So I can see all queries that are issued during page lifetime (**ASP .NET Web Forms**). I've spotted that for some reason NHibernate issues about 10 queries by id to one of my tables. I would like to improve performance by preloading the data. However I'm unable to identify the place that triggers these queries.

I know that NHibernate Profiler could put my mind at ease, but I don't have a licence to use it at work. Are there any other ways to figure out the reason of these queries. I've also analyzed mapping files but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I assumed you are using MVC ... it appears to work with plain old ASP.NET

I use [Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to find the slow points and improve my website performance. Its a framework created by StackOverflow. It gives you the queries, and by adding **Steps** you can determine who is calling it.

It also integrates with nHibernate to show the executed sql, and how long of each page render was spent in sql.

Comment: I use ASP .NET Web Forms, but thanks, could be useful in the future

Comment: I double checked and it appears to support your case.